# Slide JS CSS Image resize & Centering

Tags: jquery, css

I am helping a family friend with their site and they have a Slide JS on their homepage.  I need to shrink the slider images to 600px width and 300px high.  I also need to center the slider on the page.  I have tried some of the answers that were on this site and none of them have worked.

Here is the code:

```
/*-------------------------------------------------------
* Slide JS
//-------------------------------------------------------*/

/*Common*/
.slides-js-style {
    position:relative;
}

.slides-js-style .slides_container {    
        overflow:hidden;
    position:relative;
    display:none;
    width: 100%;

}

.slides-js-style .slides_container .slide {
    display:block;
}

.slider-next,
.slider-prev {
    position:relative;
    top: 45%;
    z-index: 10;
    width: 31px;
    height: 31px;
    text-indent: -999em;
    background-image: url(../images/slide-js-arrow.png);
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
}

.slider-prev {
    left: 20px;
    background-position: 0 0;
}

.slider-prev:hover {
    background-position: 0 100%;
}

.slider-next {
    right: 20px;
    background-position: 100% 0;
}

.slider-next:hover {
    background-position: 100% 100%;
}



/*Home Slide*/
#slides-wrap-home  {
    margin-bottom: 60px;
    background: #FFF;
}

#slides-wrap-home,
#slides-wrap-home .slides_container .slide {
    width: 940px;
    height: 430px;
}

#slides-wrap-home .slide-caption {
    position:relative;
    left: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    padding: 5px 20px; 
    background: #333;
    border-bottom-left-radius: 5px; 
    -moz-border-radius-bottomleft: 5px; 
    -webkit-border-bottom-left-radius: 5px; 
}

#slides-wrap-home .slide-caption h3 {
    font-size: 16px; 
    color: #EEE;
    font-weight: 100;
}

#slides-wrap-home .slider-pagination {
    position: absolute;
    bottom: -28px;
    height: 11px;
    z-index: 20;
}

#slides-wrap-home .slider-pagination li {
    float: left;
    margin-right: 3px;
}

#slides-wrap-home .slider-pagination li a {
    display: block;
    text-indent: -999em;
    width: 11px;
    height: 11px;
    background-image: url(../images/slide-js-button.png);
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-position: 0 0;
}

#slides-wrap-home .slider-pagination li a:hover,
#slides-wrap-home .slider-pagination li.current a {
    background-position: 100% 0;
}



/*Post Slide*/
.post-portfolio-list-slider {
    margin-bottom: 30px;
}

.post-single-slider-blog { 
    margin-bottom: 60px;
}

.post-portfolio-list-slider,
.post-single-slider-blog,
.post-portfolio-list-slider .slides_container .slide,
.post-single-slider-blog .slides_container .slide {
    width: 560px;
    height: 350px;
}

.post-single-slider-portfolio {
    margin-bottom: 48px;
    background: #FFF;
}

.post-single-slider-portfolio,
.post-single-slider-portfolio .slides_container .slide {
    width: 940px;
    height: 500px;
}

.post-portfolio-list-slider .slider-next,
.post-portfolio-list-slider .slider-prev {
    opacity: 0; 
    filter: alpha(opacity=0); 
}

.post-slider-wrap .slider-pagination {
    position: absolute;
    bottom: -28px;
    height: 9px;
    z-index: 20;
}

.post-slider-wrap .slider-pagination li {
    float: left;
    margin-right: 3px;
}

.post-slider-wrap .slider-pagination li a {
    display: block;
    text-indent: -999em;
    width: 9px;
    height: 9px;
    background-image: url(../images/post-slider-btn.png);
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-position: 0 0;
}

.post-slider-wrap .slider-pagination li a:hover,
.post-slider-wrap .slider-pagination li.current a {
    background-position: 100% 0;
}
```

Any help would be appreciated, thanks!

Revised here is the HTML code:

```
    <link rel='stylesheet' id='slideshow-css'  href='/Portals/174841/js/slideshow.css?ver=1.0.1' type='text/css' media='screen' />
<script type='text/javascript' src='/Portals/174841/js/jquery.js?ver=1.7.1'></script>
<script type='text/javascript' src='/Portals/174841/js/jquery.scripts.js?ver=1.0.1'></script>
<script type='text/javascript' src='/Portals/174841/js/custom.js?ver=1.0.1'></script>





<div id="slides-wrap-home" class="slides-js-style" data-loader="/Portals/174841/images/slider-loader.gif">
<div class="slides_container">
<div class="slide">
<img width="940" height="430" src="/Portals/174841/images/IMG_20120126_102410-940x430.jpg" class="wp-featured-image" alt="Dimensional Letters" />   </div>
<div class="slide">
<img width="940" height="430" src="/Portals/174841/images/133498_297690699994_98792189994_1198958_5498342_o-940x430.jpg" class="wp-featured-image" alt="Vehicle Graphics" />    </div>
<div class="slide">
<img width="940" height="430" src="/Portals/174841/images/IMG_20110829_143414-940x430.jpg" class="wp-featured-image" alt="Cabinet Sign Faces" />    </div>
<div class="slide">
<img width="940" height="430" src="/Portals/174841/images/CIMG2573-940x430.jpg" class="wp-featured-image" alt="Wall Vinyl" />   </div>
<div class="slide">
<img width="940" height="430" src="/Portals/174841/images/cimg1622.jpg" class="wp-featured-image" alt="Window Decals" />    </div>
</div><!--end slides_container-->
</div><!--end slides-wrap-->
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

**I also need to center the slider on the page**

To center the main content on the page,
you can use this:

```
    .center-content {
                width:600px;
                margin: 0 auto;
               }



 <div class="center-content"></div>
```

Comment: Ah thanks RPM, sorry took me so long to respond I never got the email there was an update :)  Did you still need to see HTML?

Answer (score 0):

We really need the HTML to fully understand how to answer your question, but I think this may help

```
      .slides-js-style {
           position:relative;
           width: 600px;
           height: 300px;
            }
```

To center the div , you have to place the div with the class="slides" into another div like the previous answer

```
       <div class="center">

           slider here...

        </div>
```

THen update the css file

```
         .center{
         text-align: center;
         text-align: -moz-center;
         text-align: -webkit-center;
         position: relative;
          }
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to modify the `.slides-js-style` definition:

```
.slides-js-style {
  overflow: hidden;
  height: 300px;
  width: 600px;
}
```